# Manipulation of gene expression using VP16 fusion and engrailed fusion to a transcription factor?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, development, experimental-design

Today, a presenter briefly mentioned that gene expression in sea urchins during development might be manipulated using VP16 and engrailed fusions.

On a slide, it said that expression might be increased by mRNA injection or "VP16 fusion to binding domain of TF" and decreased by antisense morpholinos or "engrailed fusion to binding domain of TF".

I understand mRNA injection and antisense morpholinos, but I am unclear about the roles of VP16 and engrailed in this context. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: VP16-activation domain fusion to a DBD can make the  hybrid protein get strongly and easily activatable. Check this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3047590) out.. quite an old one

Comment: @WYSIWYG: thanks, that addressed the first part of the question.  Apparently, genetic manipulation in sea urchin embryos is quite tricky, so I'm not surprised to see a rather old paper as a reference for a technique.

Comment: And I found the answer to the second part: http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/21/4709.abstract. @WYSIWG, if you want to write your part as an answer, I can add this part and mark the whole question as answered.

Comment: sure..no problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VP16 is a herpesvirus derived protein transcription factor, which activates the early genes of the viral infection cycle. The activation domain (AD) which is formed by the 78-amino acids from the C-terminal, can be fused to DNA binding domain of other protein transcription factors, [such as GAL4](http://www.jbc.org/content/271/9/4827.full), to make a hybrid protein that constitutively and strongly activates transcription, without the requirement of any ligands. VP16-AD interacts with [TBP, TFIID, SAGA histone acetyltransferase complex](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12297514), and PC4 [(transcriptional coactivator positive cofactor 4)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15654739) to drive transcription.

The *engrailed* gene, from Drosophila, is a transcriptional repressor.  When the repressor domain is fused to transcription factors, the fusion results in [trans-dominant negative functions of the transcription factor (phenocopying loss of function mutations in the target genes).](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/21/4709)